# Resetting My.Settings variable to Default values

Tags: vb.net, my.settings

How can i reset the my.settings variables that i've changed during debugging the application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to restore to default values:

[My.Settings.Reset()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reset%28v=vs.100%29)